# Why does Atom's Remote FTP package give the error "unable to parse PASV server response"?

Tags: linux, ftp

I'm relatively new to FTP. My friend and I are attempting to collaborate on a project. He has created an FTP server but, when I connect through the Atom editor's "Remote FTP" package, I'm given the error `unable to parse PASV server response`. Upon further research, this error doesn't seem to be an error specific to Atom but a broader error defined by the FTP protocol. I also couldn't connect through WinSCP and, after switching to FileZilla, was able to get FTP working. I would rather have Atom's FTP package work for convenience. Could someone explain the meaning of the error and what can be done to fix it?

I receive this error in WinSCP:

> Timeout detected. (control connection) Could not retrieve directory
>   listing Error listing directory '/'.

My friend's server is actually a router running Advanced Tomato. There is an external storage device plugged into the USB port where all the files are located.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that the Atom FTP client isn't handling passive mode correctly. There may be a setting to deal with it, or if it has an interactive mode you may have to send `SET PASV` somehow.

Answer (score 1):

After further testing and research, I discovered my network to be the cause of the problem. I use tethering as my primary network connection (my carrier is T-Mobile though carrier isn't relevant to the problem as I understand it).

Apparently, FTP is known to have bugs over cellular networks according to [this post I found](https://superuser.com/questions/880961/ftp-not-working-with-mobile-tethering).

> Due to its architecture the FTP protocol does not work very well in
>   environments making use of NAT. NAT is heavily used in mobile networks
>   and the used helper applications are sometimes buggy, which might
>   explain the difference you see. There might be other reasons while it
>   fails in one network but succeeds in the other but without having lots
>   of details about the networks all is speculation.
>
> I strongly recommend to move away from FTP and instead use SFTP, that
>   is file transfer over SSH. FileZilla supports SFTP but you need an SSH
>   server setup at the server side. But don't confuse SFTP with FTPS
>   which is FTP with TLS and has even more problems in environments using
>   NAT.

I connected with SFTP and everything works reliably now. Hopefully this post is helpful to someone.